# How to compare 2 tuples (files) in Pig Script

Tags: compare, tuples, apache-pig, bigdata

I am new to Pig scripting and am having problem in comparing two tuples.

There are two files:

- `random` = having sequence of 6 numbers
- `allposs` = having sequence of 5 numbers

I want to count for all the rows in `allposs`, the sequence occurrence from file `random`.

There can be 2 possibilities:

1. sequence occurs in first 5 numbers of `random`
2. sequence occurs in last 5 numbers of `random`

   ```
   A = load 'random' using PigStorage(':') as (bsid1:int, bsid2:int, bsid3:int, bsid4:int, bsid5:int, bsid6:int);
   B = load 'Allposs' using PigStorage(':') as (bsid1:int, bsid2:int, bsid3:int, bsid4:int, bsid5:int);
   C = FILTER A BY (A.bsid1==B.bsid1 AND A.bsid2==B.bsid2 AND 
       A.bsid3==B.bsid3 AND A.bsid4==B.bsid4 AND A.bsid5==B.bsid5) OR 
       (A.bsid2==B.bsid1 AND A.bsid3==B.bsid2 AND A.bsid4==B.bsid3 AND 
       A.bsid5==B.bsid4 AND A.bsid6==B.bsid5);

   C = GROUP B ALL;

   D = FOREACH C GENERATE COUNT(B);<br/>

   DUMP D;
   ```

Please help me in correcting this Pig script.

Comment: Can you give some sample input with the output you'd like to have for this?

Comment: @LiMuBei: There are two input files:<br/>
1) Random<br/>
(421, 423, 422, 423, 422, 424)<br/>
.
.
.<br/>
2) Allposs:<br/>
(421, 422, 422, 424, 423)<br/>
(422, 423, 421, 424, 421)
.
.<br/>
Now for each row of Allposs file i need to find the number of times every row in Allposs has occurred in Random file.<br/>
Output file would be the same Allposs file with an added column 'Frequency'<br/>
(421, 422, 422, 424, 423, 4) - If this sequence has occurred 4 times in random file<br/>
(422, 423, 421, 424, 421, 8) - If this sequence has occurred 8 times in random file